# High quality image picked from gallery or captured from camera

Tags: android, image, android-camera, crop, android-gallery

I have 3 tasks:

1. Pick image from gallery
2. Capture image from camera
3. Crop image from 1 or 2.

The quality of image must be good.

Are there any solution for my problem? May be some libraries?

Comment: what you have tried so far ?

Comment: You have tried anything yet ? and did you get any problem ?

Comment: There are so much problems that I decided to start from clear advice like answer.

Comment: Now the problem is using this code http://stackoverflow.com/a/20261321/1012234 I can not crop image like square. I'll show you: http://take.ms/6379o

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Android, by default, actually has all those you enumerated.

1. To pick an image from gallery

   ```
   Intent pickPhoto = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
   startActivityForResult(pickPhoto, FROM_GALLERY);
   ```
2. To capture image from camera

   ```
   Intent takePicture = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
   startActivityForResult(takePicture, FROM_CAMERA);
   ```
3. To fetch the results of the intents above and the do the cropping

   ```
   @Override
   public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
       super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
       switch (requestCode) {
       case FROM_GALLERY:
       case FROM_CAMERA: {
           if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
               Uri selectedImage = data.getData();

               Intent cropIntent = new Intent("com.android.camera.action.CROP");
               cropIntent.setDataAndType(selectedImage, "image/*");
               cropIntent.putExtra("crop", "true");
               cropIntent.putExtra("aspectX", 1);
               cropIntent.putExtra("aspectY", 1);
               cropIntent.putExtra("outputX", MAX_WIDTH);
               cropIntent.putExtra("outputY", MAX_HEIGHT);
               cropIntent.putExtra("return-data", true);
               startActivityForResult(cropIntent, PICTURE_CROP);
           }
           break;
       }
       case PICTURE_CROP: {
           if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
               final Bundle extras = data.getExtras();

               if (extras != null) {
                   Bitmap photo = extras.getParcelable("data");

                   // Hurray! You now have the photo as a Bitmap
               }
           }
           break;
       }
       }
   }
   ```

Update:

According to this [post](http://commonsware.com/blog/2013/01/23/no-android-does-not-have-crop-intent.html) you should not use `com.android.camera.action.CROP` since this does not exist in all devices. In that post, he also enumerated alternatives which I will also list here:

1. https://github.com/lvillani/android-cropimage
2. https://github.com/biokys/cropimage

Comment: What is ParseManager?

Comment: Sorry, that was copied from one of my projects. I have edited my answer to remove project specific code.

Comment: Your code is working for me but I cannot crop square image by default. Look the screen: http://take.ms/6379o

Comment: What values are you using for MAX_WIDTH and MAX_HEIGHT? You can also try removing those parameters.

Comment: MAX_WIDTH = 1000; MAX_HEIGHT = 1000; Yes, I can remove them but I realy need max. size of 1000. Besides, when I removed them I've got infinite loading dialog.

Comment: I came across this [post](http://commonsware.com/blog/2013/01/23/no-android-does-not-have-crop-intent.html). Maybe this is your problem. The first link can also be seen as an answer to a similar [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14189247/com-android-camera-action-crop-alternative)

Comment: Thanks for your help, I'll try other crop lib.